# Cognos 11 Sort A to Z and Identify change with previous line

Tags: cognos

I am looking to implement in Cognos 11 a simple formula I am currently doing externally in Excel.

=IF(AND(P3=P2,O3<>O2),"Change","No Change")

After sorting alphabetically, if value A is same as the line above and value B is different from the line above, it identifies a change

Any tip how to get it directly in cognos?

Thanks

Comment: 2nd Cognos question in 2 days asking how to use an Excel function in Cognos.  Excel is cell-based.  Cognos interacts with datasets, not cells.  Edit your question to be about how to do in Cognos a function that you can use in SQL.

Comment: running-difference might be a helpful function.